# "Use of" vs "Use for"

Tags: prepositions

> She has no use of the book I gave her.
>
> She has no use for the book I gave her.

Which one is grammatically correct and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but they mean slightly different things.

*Use of* is an old-fashioned phrase that means, simply, the same as *use*. So,

> She has no use of the book

means the same as

> She does not use the book. (Note that we are  not told *why*.)

*To have use of* usually means that the object being used is owned by someone else. For example, *While I visited my uncle on the farm I had use of his car*.

The phrase *use for* means the same as *need*. So,

> She has no use for the book

means the same as

> She does not need the book.